# How to rewrite matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus

I have two matrices $X_1$ and $X_2$ both with dimension $n \times p$, $\boldsymbol{\beta}_1$ and $\boldsymbol{\beta}_2$ are $p-$dimensional vectors finally, $f(\cdot)$ is a monotone positive function.

\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{\mu} = \begin{pmatrix}
X_1 \boldsymbol{\beta}_1\\
f(X_2\boldsymbol{\beta}_2)
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

I'd like to rewrite $\boldsymbol{\mu}$ separating $X_1$ and $X_2$ in a matrix, $\boldsymbol{\beta}_1$ and $\boldsymbol{\beta}_2$ in other. For example, if $f(\cdot)$ is identity, that is, $f(x) = x$ the desired result is

\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{\mu} = \begin{pmatrix}
\boldsymbol{X}_1 & 0 \\
0                & \boldsymbol{X}_2
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
\boldsymbol{\beta}_1\\
\boldsymbol{\beta}_2
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

Comment: Matrices are linear operators. If the function $f$ is nonlinear, I don’t think there will be a “clean” way to do this.